# Custom autocomplete function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

**UPDATE**

With the help and suggestions taken from the [@Ziv Weissman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4162955/ziv-weissman) and [@Fribu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290326/fribu) I re-wrote the whole autocomplete function.

If anybody needs it he/she can download from [here](https://github.com/saineshmamgain/autofill).

Thanks StackOverFlow community.

---

I am creating a jquery autocomplete function. The function that I created is working fine with single text box. But as soon as I am implementing it on another text box in same page it is behaving unexpectedly. It opens and closes the autocomplete list.

here is my code for autofill.js:

```
function setUl(result) {
    var $ul = $('<ul>');
    if (result !== undefined) {
        $.each(result, function (k, v) {
            $ul.append('<li data-value="' + v.value + '">' + v.label + '</li>');
        });
    }
    return $ul;
}
$.fn.autofill = function (options) {
    if (options == undefined) {
        options = {};
    }
    var $currentInput = $(this);
    var autoCompleteData = $currentInput.data('autofill');
    var listId='autofill-' + (new Date().getTime()).toString(16);
    $currentInput.on('keyup focus', function (e) {

        var query = $(this).val();
        var result = $.grep(autoCompleteData, function (v) {
            return v.label.search(new RegExp(query, 'i')) !== -1;
        });
        $ul = setUl(result, $currentInput);
        $ul.attr('id', listId);
        $ul.addClass('autofill-show');
        $ul.attr('data-target',$currentInput.attr('id'));
        var position = $currentInput.position();
        $ul.css({
            width: $currentInput.width() + parseInt($currentInput.css('padding-left'), 10) + parseInt($currentInput.css('padding-right'), 10),
            position: 'absolute',
            top: position.top + $currentInput.outerHeight(),
            left: position.left
        });
        if ($ul.find('li').length >= 6) {
            $ul.css({
                height: '130px',
                'overflow-y': 'scroll'
            });
        }
        if (result !== undefined) {
            if ($(e.target).attr('id') !== $currentInput.attr('id') && $($(e.target).parent()[0]).attr('id') !== listId) {
                destroy($ul);
            }
            $currentInput.after($ul);
        }
        $currentInput.trigger('onChange', [query, result]);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.autofill-show li', function (e) {
        if($ul!==undefined && $($(this).parent()[0]).attr('id')==$ul.attr('id')){
            $ul.trigger('onSelect', [$(this).text(), $(this).data('value')]);
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $(document).on('onSelect', '#'+listId,function (e, label, value) {
        $currentInput.val(label);
        if ($.isFunction(options.onSelect)) {
            options.onSelect(label, value);
        }
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') !== $currentInput.attr('id') && $($(e.target).parent()[0]).attr('id') !== listId) {
            destroy($ul);
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $(document).on('onChange', '#'+$currentInput.attr('id'), function (e, query, result) {
        if($ul!==undefined && $($(this).parent()[0]).attr('id')==$ul.attr('id')) {
            result = $.grep(autoCompleteData, function (v) {
                return v.label.search(new RegExp('\^' + query + '\$', "gi")) !== -1;
            });
            if ($.isFunction(options.onChange)) {
                options.onChange(query, result[0]);
            }
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        console.log($(e.target));
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') !== $currentInput.attr('id') && $($(e.target).parent()[0]).attr('id') !== listId) {
            destroy($ul);
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
};
function destroy($ul) {
    $ul.remove();
}
```

Here is my css:

```
.autofill-show{
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin:0;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
.autofill-show li{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}

.autofill-show li:hover{
    background: #9bcea3;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And this is how I am calling my function:

```
$('#autofill').autofill();
$('#autofill_2').autofill();
```

Here is the fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/saineshmamgain/cs6g13q9/2/

Comment: It will help us help you if you convert this to code snippet or fiddle, also include your html for autofill and autofill-2 (btw recommend to change to autofill_2)

Comment: @ZivWeissman Added a fiddle link. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely you are targeting the same elements with your selectors, you need to add to your selector something unique per element ID, something like currentId = '#' + $i.attr('id'); I will look at it later when I have time

Comment: ok. thanks for your time.

Comment: This is not the solution, but when you disable the destroy of the following line, you kan see the behaviour of the autosuggest. It looks like one item handles both of them. I guess if you fix that, the problem will be solved too

 

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') !== $i.attr('id') && $($(e.target).parent()[0]).attr('id') !== $ul.attr('id')) {
          //destroy($ul);
        }
      });

Comment: @CodeZilla you have multiple problems in your code. you have multiple event binding and also if you select item in one list it will also be writteln in another...  try to rethink your events and structure... and maybe even variable names to get a clear picture.

Comment: @Kootsj yes but that `destroy()` is when i will click outside the input box the list should close.

Comment: @Fribu Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Actually I was creating this for a single input box and when I was creating this I only had one input in mind. but when I am using it for two inputs it seems all the events are firing twice.

Comment: @Fribu updated my question by naming variables and also now item in one list is not updating other. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @CodeZilla the thing is, your code will never work with this statement $(document).on('click', function (e) at least not twice on a page. You want to close the autocomplete if user clicks outside of the input. But... you have to make sure you bind this event only once. You can: save state of bind in a global variable, make sure the naming is unique so no other plugins override this by mistake or... change the event to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, and others helped, this is a problem with your events and selectors.

One solution can be adding unique ID to the UL created, not "datetime based".
Each time you will destory a specific ID, and recreate it.
The events will be triggers via HTML (added onclick=...) and dealth with current/parent level with jQUERY.

I've updated this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x412yn60/)

It might have things that are leftovers from your fiddle which I don't have time to perfect... I'll leave it to you.

The solution looks something like this:

```
function setUl(result) {
    var $ul = $('<ul>');
    if (result !== undefined) {
        $.each(result, function (k, v) {
            $ul.append('<li data-value="' + v.value + '" onclick="clickHandle(this)">' + v.label + '</li>');
        });
    }
    return $ul;
}

function clickHandle(ele){
var label = $(ele).text();
var value = $(ele).data('value');
var inputId = $(ele).parent("ul").attr("data-target");
$('#'+inputId).val(label);
        if ($.isFunction(options.onSelect)) {
            options.onSelect(label, value);
        }
}

$.fn.autofill = function (options) {
    if (options == undefined) {
        options = {};
    }
    var $currentInput = $(this);
    console.log($($currentInput).attr('id'));
    var autoCompleteData = $currentInput.data('autofill');
    var listId='autofill_' + $currentInput.attr('id');
    $currentInput.on('keyup focus', function (e) {

        var query = $(this).val();
        var result = $.grep(autoCompleteData, function (v) {
            return v.label.search(new RegExp(query, 'i')) !== -1;
        });
        if($('#'+listId)){
          $('#'+listId).remove();
        }
        $ul = setUl(result, $currentInput);
        $ul.attr('id',listId);
        $ul.addClass('autofill-show');
        $ul.attr('data-target',$currentInput.attr('id'));
        var position = $currentInput.position();
        $ul.css({
            width: $currentInput.width() + parseInt($currentInput.css('padding-left'), 10) + parseInt($currentInput.css('padding-right'), 10),
            position: 'absolute',
            top: position.top + $currentInput.outerHeight(),
            left: position.left
        });
        if ($ul.find('li').length >= 6) {
            $ul.css({
                height: '130px',
                'overflow-y': 'scroll'
            });
        }
        if (result !== undefined) {
            destroy($ul);
            $currentInput.after($ul);
        }
        $currentInput.trigger('onChange', [query, result]);
    });  
    //end key up 

    $('#'+listId).on('onSelect',function (e, label, value) {
        $currentInput.val(label);
        if ($.isFunction(options.onSelect)) {
            options.onSelect(label, value);
        }
        destroy($ul);
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $(document).on('onChange', '#'+$currentInput.attr('id'), function (e, query, result) {
        if($ul!==undefined && $($(this).parent()[0]).attr('id')==$ul.attr('id')) {
            result = $.grep(autoCompleteData, function (v) {
                return v.label.search(new RegExp('\^' + query + '\$', "gi")) !== -1;
            });
            if ($.isFunction(options.onChange)) {
                options.onChange(query, result[0]);
            }
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $currentInput.on('blur', function (e) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
        destroy($ul);
        }, 100);
    });
};
function destroy($ul) {
    $ul.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solved my major problem. I will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly your quation(code):

```
hidden
```

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/9f1se76z/2/)